# How to drop duplicates based on specific condition regarding how close the dates are using python?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have the following dataframe:

```
> df = pd.DataFrame( columns = ['Name','Change Date','Final Date']) 
> df['Name'] = ['Alexandra','Alexandra','Alexandra','Alexandra','Bobby','Bobby']
> df['Change Date'] =['2019-04-12','2019-04-28','2019-05-21','2019-05-30','2019-03-11','2019-03-27'] 
> df['Final Date'] =['2019-04-15','2019-04-15','2019-05-27','2019-05-27','2019-03-20','2019-03-20']
```

I want to drop all duplicates yet only keep the row whereby the change date is closest to each final date in order to give the following dataframe:

```
> df = pd.DataFrame( columns = ['Name','Change Date','Final Date']) 
> df['Name'] = ['Alexandra','Alexandra','Bobby'] 
> df['Change Date'] =['2019-04-12','2019-05-30','2019-03-27']
> df['Final Date'] =['2019-04-15','2019-05-27','2019-03-20']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert both columns to datetimes, subtract by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) and get absolute values by [`Series.abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html). Last get indices of minimal values per groups with [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) and select original rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df['Final Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Final Date'])
df['Change Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Change Date'])
df['diff'] = df['Final Date'].sub(df['Change Date']).abs()

df1 = df.loc[df.groupby(['Name','Final Date'])['diff'].idxmin()]
print (df1)
        Name Change Date Final Date   diff
0  Alexandra  2019-04-12 2019-04-15 3 days
3  Alexandra  2019-05-30 2019-05-27 3 days
5      Bobby  2019-03-27 2019-03-20 7 days
```

If possible duplicated minimal values per groups use:

```
df1 = df[df.groupby(['Name','Final Date'])['diff'].transform('min').eq(df['diff'])]
```

Or if need grouping by `Name` only column and seelct both minimal `3 days` values create Series with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and `min` and compare by `diff`, last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.groupby('Name')['diff'].transform('min').eq(df['diff'])]
print (df1)
        Name Change Date Final Date   diff
0  Alexandra  2019-04-12 2019-04-15 3 days
3  Alexandra  2019-05-30 2019-05-27 3 days
5      Bobby  2019-03-27 2019-03-20 7 days
```